# What is the use of report level in dimensional level metric in MicroStrategy?

Tags: microstrategy

MicroStrategy allows us to create a dimensional metric. For example, I can create a revenue metric to be calculated at the category level. This level can be mentioned as part of the metric definition.

What is not clear to me is, why should we have report level along with the particular level like category? What would be the scenario where we should retain the report level vs. remove the report level while defining the metric.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the report level, calculations will always be performed at category level. SQL will be something like that

```
select category, sum(amount) 
    from table 
    group by category
```

for example there are two attributes in Report 1) Country 2) Category

Scenario 1: Amount of each category is constant among the countries, the above sql works
Scenario 2: Amount of each category is also divided among the countries, the above sql wont work and report level is required. The required sql for scenario 2 should be

```
select country,category, sum(amount) 
    from table 
    group by country,category
```